# Circle and text alignment CSS3

Tags: css, alignment, geometry, text-align

I would like to align the text under the circle, perfectly on the middle.

Here a snippet (I simplified everything because circle and text are handled by angular so they are some difference between my screenshot and the snippet)

```css
.circle2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position:relative;

}
.wrapper2:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  top:7px;
  height: 3px;
  background: RoyalBlue;

}
.advanced2 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.circleActive2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <span>
    <span><div class="circle2 advanced2" ></div>test</span>
    <span><div class="circle2 advanced2 circleActive2" ></div>test2</span>
    <span><div class="circle2 advanced2" ></div>test3</span>
        <span><div class="circle2 advanced2" ></div>test4</span>
        <span><div class="circle2 advanced2" ></div>test5</span>
      </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.circles {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}

.circles:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 7px;
  height: 3px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
}

.circles > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;  
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
}

.circle.active {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div><span class="circle"></span>test</div>
  <div><span class="circle active"></span>test2</div>
  <div><span class="circle"></span>test3</div>
  <div><span class="circle"></span>test4</div>
  <div><span class="circle"></span>test5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So If I understand well, circle > div Selects all <div> elements where the parent is a circle element and felx-direction: column + align-items: center align perfectly as expected ?

Comment: [The > selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)  `flex-direction: column; align-items: center;` puts the elements on their own lines and aligns them vertically

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should work like the following:
You can change the max-width and the margin of the ".wrapper2" to without a problem.

```css
.wrapper2 {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:50px auto;
}

.wrapper2 > span {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
 -moz-justify-content: space-around;
 justify-content: space-around;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.wrapper2:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
 top:7px;
 left:0;
 height: 4px;
 background: RoyalBlue;
}

.advanced2 {
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 margin: 0 auto 5px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 background: RoyalBlue;
 z-index: 2;
}

.circleActive2 {
 margin: -4px auto 1px;
 width: 26px;
 height: 26px;
}

.advanced2 + i {
 font-style:normal;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
  <span>
    <span><div class="advanced2"></div><i>test</i></span>
    <span><div class="advanced2 circleActive2"></div><i>test2</i></span>
    <span><div class="advanced2"></div><i>test3</i></span>
    <span><div class="advanced2"></div><i>test4</i></span>
    <span><div class="advanced2"></div><i>test5</i></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Hope I could help!